# JPA transaction from servlet

Tags: java, jpa, jta

I have a Java EE 6 servlet that creates an instance of `FooBarModelImpl` and this class uses JPA to fetch some resources.

```
public class FooBarModelImpl
{

    @Resource
    UserTransaction ut;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="fooBarUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addPackage(UpgradePackageEntity p)
    {
        try{
            ut.begin();
            em.persist(p);
            ut.commit();
        } catch (..) {}
    }
}
```

The persistence unit is configured this way:

```
<persistence-unit name="fooBarUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
```

My question is how could I get rid of dealing with `ut.begin()` and `ut.commit()` manually? I'd like to use JPA so that the container deals with the transaction management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure that your class `FooBarModelImpl` is managed by the container in order to safely inject the `PersistenceContext`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9447039/870122) regarding this point.

Once this is done, simply remove the `begin()` and `commit()` method invocations, because the transaction boundaries are automatically set by the container.

You'll have no more need to keep the reference to the `UserTransaction` object, either.